# Rspec; How to use should not include?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Right now i am using not_to eq, how can i use should not include in following scenario?

```
Code:   
expect(object.method('param1')).not_to eq(array)

Console:    
expected: value != ["value1", "value2", 
    "value3","value4"]

got: ["value2", "value3"]
```

Comment: Why do you use "eq" if you want "include"? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `include` matcher ([docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher))

```
expect(object.method('param1')).not_to include(*array)
```

Comment: What is difference between 'not_to include' and 'should_not inlcude'?

Comment: It's a difference between old `should` syntax and new `expect` http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/ it's preferable to use `expect`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
expect(object.method('param1')).not_to include("value1", "value2")
```

The expectation would fail if the array returned by `method` contained *any* of the listed values.